# Increasing the gain of a BJT amplifier without affecting dc bias

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, common-emitter

Reading through my textbook, I came across a basic common-emitter amplifier that drives a load. Please have a look at the circuit, and input/output waveforms shown in the image below.

[image: Image adapted from Electronic Devies, Thomas L. Floyd]

How would one increase the gain without affecting the DC bias? From my point of view, the value of RE would determine this. Decreasing this resistance would increase the base current, thereby increasing the collector current. Am I correct in my reasoning? I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: In your setup,the gain is expressed as -Rc/rE,because the capacitor shunts RE.

Comment: That is the voltage gain

Comment: It would help to know what RL is, and the frequency range of interest. There's one obvious change you can make, but whether it's relevant depends on the additional info.

Comment: Are you asking this because of the analogue electronics tutorial due today at UCT?

Comment: In the following Rl == Rc. Vl == V_Rc. AND Re = transistor internal emitter resistance.  || Gain = VdcRc x 38.4 [!!!!!!] - Really. So here gain = [12-8.2] * 38.4 = 145.9. This is because gain = Rl/Re and Re = 26/Ie . For Ie ~~= Ic you get V_Rl = Il.Rl = Ie.Rl. Play with that and you end up with the "magic" Gain = 38.4 x Vl | SO the DC collector bias point is crucial in setting the gain.

Comment: @Russel McMahon I found more consistent the magic gain as Gain=VdcRc/Vt. It is obviuosly equivalent to Gain=VdcRc x 38.4 but a ratio of two omogeneous (and well known) quantities  sounds to me much better than a 38.4 in unknown (actually V^-1) units.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is a bit too complex for me. In simple terms, what circuit parameters do I need to change to increase the gain?

Comment: @carloc There is no magic in my "magic". But you have to look into what I provided. The Re~= 26/Ie is a fundamental property of the silicon junction and derives from the standard transistor models with appropriate physical parameters inserted. [**Dealt with quite well here**](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Theory/re_model.htm) . || Re ~= (Boltman's constant x Temperature_degrees_K) / (electron charge x mA emitter current)

Comment: @carloc I appreciate the merit of a slightly more complex gain formula in some cases - but, being able to look at an amplifier and visually approximate max small signal & full swing gains "by inspection" is extremely valuable (AND a good party trick :-). || Small signal gain max ~= 38.4 x Vsupply - a bit. || Full swing gain ~= 38.4 x Vsupply/2 - a bit. Size of "a bit" can be assessed from device saturation, circuit & experience. | Tell people that with a single Si transistor BJT stage and 10V supply they CANNOT get more small signal voltage gain than about 380 and they will not believe you.

Comment: MAXIMUM gain from a single stage silicon bipolar transistor = 38.4 x DC_voltage) across_Rc. For details see answers and comments below. This is is full bypassed emitter resistor (which means: C2 is large enough that its impedance at frequencies of interest is very small compared to external resistor RE. This means that internal emitter resistance Re affects gain = Rc/Re. At eg 1 mA Re = 26 Ohms . So voltage across Re is V = I x R = 26 mV. The same 1 mA flows in Rc so here V_Rc would be 1 V. So gain = V_Rc/V_Re = 1V/26 mV = 38.4. | Again - see answers and comments for where 26/mA comes from.

Comment: @Russel McMahon , oh yes your's too is a good point, let's say you mean something like "it's easier to make a multiplication" to ballpark max gain. From my point of view it's just that 38.4 (or say 40 is good enough) is one more "magic number" to be remembered, against 26mV which is engraved in my mind since school era. Then about people's myth's you're quite right, just try to tell someone that given the same VdcRc both a bulky 2N3055 and a  tiny BC547 will show same AC gain.

Comment: @carloc Indeed 40 IS good enough :-) - as it's 40 at 20C and 38.4 at 25C, or was it ....? :-) . Agh.

Comment: Oh yes  :) something like that, I just happily round it off, all in all it's just 5% or so, many other factors can do worst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, decreasing \$R_\textrm{E}\$ would increase gain, but this would violate your constraint **"without changing DC bias"**.

In that circuit in-band voltage gain is basically \$A_\text{v}=-g_\text{m}R_\text{C}\$
*-it should be RC||RL, but the latter is not given, I assume is open circuit-*

Then \$g_\text{m}=I_\textrm{C}/V_\text{T}\$ and finally \$I_\text{C}\approx I_\text{E}=V_\text{E}/R_\text{E}\$ as long as we do not drive transistor out of active region.

So putting all toghether $$A_\text{v}\approx - \frac{V_\text{E}}{V_\text{T}}\,\frac{R_\text{C}}{R_\text{E}}=
-\frac{2.13\,\text{V}}{26\,\text{mV}}\times\frac{1\,\text{k}\Omega}{560\,\Omega}\approx -145$$ with your numbers

and indeed lowering \$R_\textrm{E}\$ increases gain BUT you have to consider also that this is surely  going to reduce output dynamics (i.e allowed output voltage swing), everything in life is a tradeoff.

Also, generally,  take care to verify reduced \$R_\textrm{E}\$ will extra load base bias voltage divider with changes in \$V_\textrm{E}\$ too (your circuit has quite heavy divider though).

Finally, note as we don't need any BJT parameters (e.g. \$\beta\$) to make rather accurate gain calculations, that's a well-engineered circuit!

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I haven't really covered too much content on transistors, so I am not too sure of the gain you have calculated in terms of $g_m$. So, what parameters of the circuit could be changed to increase gain without changing the DC bias? You stated that changing RE would violate the constraint. What else can I vary along with RE in order to keep the constraint?

Comment: So to vary gm (I believe that problem is for someone who knows what it is) you have to vary Ic and hence bias point: **forbidden**. The other term in the gain expression (its knowledge required) is Rc||RL, if you vary Rc you change bias point again: **forbidden**. So what remains?

Comment: From what I see, RE remains?

Comment: @abruzzi26 He and I are saying that it can't be done - while RE is the external emitter resistor, what matters and what we are dealing with is what I called Re = internal emitter resistance of the actual transistor. The external RE is bypassed for AC by C2 so does not affect AC gain. Gain then becomes Rc/Re. But what I said and he says is that Re varies with mA in Re and in transistor and in Rc = all the same current (almost Ib slightly affects this). When you re arrange this and look  [**here**](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Theory/re_model.htm) you find Gain and bias are hard-related. Alas.